# PostGIS Out of Memory during bulk insert

Tags: postgis, osm2po, memory

I am attempting to import OSM road data using an SQL file generated by OSM2PO.  However I keep getting the following error:

> ERROR: out of memory 
>   SQL state: 53200 
>   Detail: Failed on request of size 1048576.

This would suggest there is some memory limit set in the config file to only 1MB.  However, I have set my work_mem to 16MB and my shared_mem to 500MB in the config file and reloaded it, plus completely restarted the server.  I have also tried manually setting the work_mem for the session.

The really annoying thing is that I have used this process to import a much larger dataset into PostGIS on a Netbook computer with considerably less physical memory.  I vaguely remember having to tweak some setting to do it but for the life of me I can't remember what it was and the config file looks like the original factory settings!

So, if it is not the work_mem that is at fault, which setting should I adjust? (I'm using PostGIS 2 and Postgresql 9.1 on Windows 7 32 bit).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an assumption:

osm2po builds blocks of 25 data rows per insert for performance reasons and to avoid memory issues.
Do you import it in one single Transaction (parameter -1 or --single-transaction)?

Comment: I just loaded the SQL into pgAdmin and pressed 'Go', so I guess that counts as a single transaction.  My inference from your comment its that I should do it from the command line as multiple transactions.

Comment: This is the reason. You had better used the psql commandline tool.

Comment: Just did (well, psql from cmd actually) and it was mind-blowingly fast!  Job done.  Thanks.